# How can we remove a "\" backslash character from a string in java?

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out how we can remove a special character along with its preceding letters within a string.

Let's suppose, there a string with `"ABC\n000111"`. In this case we have to remove the `"ABC\"` character from the string. So, the result would be `n000111`.

Can someone help me find the efficient way of doing this?

Comment: When you say "ABC\n000111", do you mean a string with that **content** or a string literal that looks like that? Because that's a huge difference. One contains the character \ and n and the other contains a newline character (which is represented in a string literal as `\n`). What does `myString.length()` return on that value?

Comment: Does the string *genuinely* include a backslash, and is that definitely *not* meant to be paired with the "n" as an escape for "new line"? If you could provide more context in the question it would be really helpful.

Comment: you can simply loop on your string's characters, find the index of the character you are looking for (backslash) and create a new substring with String.substring(int startIndex)

Answer (score 2):

The Java string literal `"ABC\n000111"` doesn't contain a backslash: `\n` is a special character sequence, meaning a single character for a (unix) [newline](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

If you want to replace `\n` with `n`, you can do so:

```
System.out.println("ABC\n000111".replace('\n', 'n'));
```

If you want to replace everything up to and including the `\n` with `n`, you can do so:

```
System.out.println("ABC\n000111".replaceAll("^.*\n", "n"));
```